# How to check if a person belongs to the receiving list of an email in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, mailing-lists

Occasionally I need to check if some person receives a specific email or not, or why that email was sent to some people (to remove them from that mail group), but there are a lot of mailing lists in the To and Cc fields, each may recursively contains a lot of sub mailing lists.

I can click on each group to see its members and child groups and look for the name manually. But obviously it takes a lot of time and error-prone. Is there anyway to quickly confirm that the person is among the recipients of some email? Bonus points if it's possible to show which group in the mail contains that person.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

1. Search the person via Home > Find > Search people:

[image]

2. Click the person, scroll down and choose Membership in the pop up:
   [image]
3. You'll see a list of all the distribution lists the person is in, then you can check if the group in the To/CC/bcc fields of the message is included in the person's membership lists.

Comment: Of course I know how to check the distribution lists the person is in as said above, but to do that I just need to **hover on his name**, no need to do so complex steps as yours. But it doesn't solve my problem, because it just lists the **direct group that the user belongs**, but the mail is sent to a distribution lists multiple layers above (e.g. company branch > department > project > sub project > component > group > subgroup...)  which each level have lots of subgroups so it's impossible to go recursively and check where the user is

Comment: From what I know, I am afraid there is no built-in option in Outlook for this requirement.